# How to align button to right side of text box in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to align my button to my text boxes, meaning their right sides should be able to form a straight line but so far I have not been able to figure out how to do it (excluding margin-left, as that only works for one screen size).

[image: btn to fix]

I tried using some css between style tags to try and align it but that did not work.

btn pull-right also did not do what I wanted.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RedemptionDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-7" })

            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btnSpot" type="button" onclick="GetSpotDate(event)" style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:10px" value=@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Spot)>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Right now the button looks as pictured above. Ideally, all three components would be aligned on their right sides.

Comment: `class="float-right"` in your button element.

Comment: @Paandittya That puts it to the right of the text boxes (it's to the left now).

Comment: your image is not showing

Comment: `class="float-left"` then. I am little confused about your left-right though.

Comment: Also if you want all the elements of form to be aligned to the same side then it would be a better idea to use `class="text-<left, center or right as per ur req>"` in your `<div class="col-sm-12">`

Comment: @Paandittya Hi, I fixed the image if that makes it more easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using more bootstrap classes then this should work.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="card card-outline-secondary">
  <div class="card-body">
    <form autocomplete="off" class="form" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Start Date</label>
        <input class="form-control" required="" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg float-right" type="submit">Spot</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this puts the button directly next to the text field. Is there a way to put it directly under (on right side)? (see above pic)

Answer (score 0):

You could set flex and set justify the content with space between:

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-between"> ...</div>
```

[image]

**if you want items in the div to stack use the following**

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 d-flex flex-column"> ...</div>
```

[image]

Bootstrap flex reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: Would this allow the button to be below the text field?

Comment: @Wintress If you want them to stack use (d-flex flex-column) instead of justify-content-between